# Sending a post json with curl get error

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Im trying to create a bash script to make github pull requests here its my code:

[Gist Code](https://gist.github.com/bitgandtter/8d7b71f52d6f3fa5c01e)

I get this error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: on
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 63
{
  "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
   "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More/proper quoting:

```
body=$(printf '{"title":"%s","body":"%s","head":"clamour:%s","base":"%s"}' "$TITLE" "$DESCRIPTION" "$TARGET" "$SOURCE")
curl -H "$auth" -d "$body" "https://api.github.com/repos/clamour/$PROJECT/pulls"
```

All user-supplied variables **must** be quoted (unless you know exactly why you want to leave then unquoted).
Enclosing a variable name in `${braces}` is **not** the same as `"$quoting"`.

I find using `printf` tends to be more clear than mixing double and single quotes with variable interpolation.

Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variable names: one day you'll use `PATH=...` and then wonder why your script is broken

Comment: this one i really like

Answer (score 1):

you are using a lot of variables
try to do it like this

```
BODY="{\"title\":\"$TITLE\",\"body\":\"$DESCRIPTION\",\"head\":\"clamour\":\"$TARGET\",\"base\":\"$SOURCE\"}"
"https://api.github.com/repos/clamour/$PROJECT/pulls"
```

read also this [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: i test your solution but got the same error, maybe the command line call can bring more light, here it is:   sh test.sh -t="jenkins-api-dev-133" -d="7f1bb90659de081eb6070d7a574ec4b89489b6b8 on 2014-11-28_18-48-36" -t_b=staging -s_b=develop -p=project

Comment: host should be defenetly  in double quotes, because you are using variable in the link. For Body part you probably should use escaping, i edited the BODY part. I don't have anything to test on it right now.